# Send HTML Form as email along with attachment

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I have a react app which has a simple HTML form which has an attach file option. I want to receive this form data as an email when submitted, please help to let me know of available options.

Answer (score 0):

Email js will help to send mails using client side technology. No service will be required for it just connect email js to one of the supported mail services, create an email template and use javascript library to trigger an mail.

Comment: For sending attachment Email JS asks to purchase premium, any option to configure this free of cost?